# How to divide screen size into six parts Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to divide the screen into six part with bootstrap like the shape below

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vh` css unit to specify the viewport height for each column.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-6 {
    height: 33.33vh;
  }
}
```

```css
.container-fluid .col-sm-6 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid .col-sm-6 {
      height: 33.33vh;  
  } 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please wait to test that

Comment: that's true,but want in one row just see one div when user see in mobile device,in that your css when see in mobile device show two div in one row

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi I've updated my answer. You can use media queries to apply styles only when certain viewport width is reached.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi I didn't get your words. Please be specific about this. Have you got what you wants or there is still something that needs to be changed?

Comment: i want when see my web site in mobile device,in one row just show one div with your code in mobile device show two div per row.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi I've updated my answer. Now you will see one row only in mobile devices.

Comment: see two div so!

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi Have you make changes in HTML? I've replaced `col-xs-6` with `col-sm-6`.

Comment: oh ok please wait

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 sameHeight">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 sameHeight">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 sameHeight">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 sameHeight">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 sameHeight">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 sameHeight">
      
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

You can use twitter bootstrap classes like this and give each div same height.

```css
.sameHeight{
  height:30px;
}
```